# Lowering volume of one sound while another plays over it

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In my MenuScene.swift I have a series of random playing sounds as my game begins:

```
       let soundNames = [
        "Sound/01.mp3",
        "Sound/02.mp3",
        "Sound/03.mp3"
    ]
    let randomSoundName = soundNames[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(soundNames.count)))]
    _ = self.run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(randomSoundName, waitForCompletion: false))
```

...and in my GameViewController.swift I have a background track that plays as the game starts:

```
        // Start the background music:
    if let musicPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource:
        "Sound/BackgroundMusic.wav", ofType: nil) {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: musicPath)
        do {
            musicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            musicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
            musicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            musicPlayer.play()
        }
        catch { /* Couldn't load music file */ }
    }
```

How do I reduce the volume of the background track as the random sound plays over the top of it?

Comment: You can try `audioPlayer?.volume = 0.7` for custom volume.

Comment: How / where would I implement that?

Comment: `musicPlayer?.volume = 0.7` you have to put that where you need it, you can change volume level programmatically from 0.0 to 1.0